# JOIN 3 Rows in 1 Table to 1 Row in another Table

Tags: sql

I need to create a recordset which Joins 3 rows from one table on 1 row from another table.

At present I have:

```
   SELECT * 
     FROM tb_product_sub_cat 
LEFT JOIN tb_products ON tb_product_sub_cat.category_id = tb_products.product_subcategory 
    WHERE tb_product_sub_cat.category_name = %s
```

I also need:

```
tb_product_sub_cat.category_id = tb_products.product_subcategory2 AND
tb_product_sub_cat.category_id = tb_products.product_subcategory3
```

I need to find all products that have 'stuff' in either/or all of the product categories.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM tb_product_sub_cat 
INNER JOIN tb_products 
ON tb_product_sub_cat.category_id =   tb_products.product_subcategory2 
AND tb_product_sub_cat.category_id = tb_products.product_subcategory3 
AND   tb_product_sub_cat.category_id =  tb_products.product_subcategory  
WHERE tb_product_sub_cat.category_name = %s
```

This is my interpretation of your scenario. Let me know if this works for you or if you need elaboration.

**EDIT**

```
SELECT * FROM tb_product_sub_cat 
LEFT JOIN tb_products 
ON tb_product_sub_cat.category_id =   tb_products.product_subcategory2 
AND tb_product_sub_cat.category_id = tb_products.product_subcategory3 
AND   tb_product_sub_cat.category_id =  tb_products.product_subcategory  
WHERE tb_product_sub_cat.category_name = %s
```

Comment: Your JOIN should be a LEFT JOIN - the additional criteria doesn't necessarily mean there'll always be supporting records.

Comment: Hi Xencor, thankyou for your reply.
I tried this SQL and it unfortunately returned no results.
I have a table of Product Sub-Categories (containing an ID and NAME ex, 1 = Backpacks, 2=Bags), and a Products table with product_subcategory, product_subcategory2 & product_subcategory3.
I have one product which could have up to 3 product_subcategories.

I need to find all products that have 'stuff' in either/or all of the product categories.

:) Thanks again

Comment: @Warren Pls. see the edit as per rexem's suggestion...let me know if tht works for u

Comment: Hi Xencor,
I tried the LEFT JOIN (which returned a recordset total) but realised that it's not the recordset that's the problem, but the amount of non-distinct values in the Subcategory table.
Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

Not completely clear what you want hear but this looks like a job for UNION:-

```
    SELECT * FROM tb_product_sub_cat LEFT JOIN tb_products ON tb_product_sub_cat.category_id = tb_products.product_subcategory WHERE tb_product_sub_cat.category_name = %s 
UNION
SELECT * FROM tb_product_sub_cat LEFT JOIN tb_products ON tb_product_sub_cat.category_id = tb_products.product_subcategory2 WHERE tb_product_sub_cat.category_name = %s
UNION
SELECT * FROM tb_product_sub_cat LEFT JOIN tb_products ON tb_product_sub_cat.category_id = tb_products.product_subcategory3 WHERE tb_product_sub_cat.category_name = %s
```

Answer (score 1):

Table aliases will make your life easier:

```
   SELECT * 
     FROM tb_product_sub_cat t
LEFT JOIN tb_products tp ON t.category_id IN (tp.product_subcategory, tp.product_subcategory2, tp.product_subcategory3)
    WHERE t.category_name = %s
```